# How long should I leave my coffee for in a cafetiere (French press)?

Tags: brewing-process, ground-coffee, french-press

I'm struggling to find a good way of timing how long to let my cafetiere stand before drinking.

Is there a rule of thumb for how long I should leave it per mug? Or is there more to it than that?